# Need save an id from a drop down list of a related tables objects

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

i have this form that saves the relation between 2 tables in my db

Treatments `belongs_to :category`

Category `has_many :treatments`

When a treatment is created it should save the id of the category and i want the category to be a drop down list, here is my code for the form :

```
<%= form_for(@treatment) do |f| %>  
  <div class="field">
    <select> 
      <% Category.find(:all).each do |cat| %>   
        <option><%= cat.name %></option>  
      <% end %>
    </select>
  </div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Okey so i was able to display all the categories names but im kinda lost at how i should save the `cat.id` with the form

btw im quite new to rails if you haven't noticed :)

any thoughts ?

**UPDATE**

here is the html that is generated

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="treatment_category">Category</label>
  <br>
    <select id="category_category_id" name="category[category_id]">
    <option value="">Velja flokk</option>
    <option value="1">Nudd</option>
    <option value="2">Heilun</option>
    <option value="3">Nálastunga</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

okey noticed an error in the html changed `id="treatment_category_id"` and now in my show view i see the categorie connected to the treatment but its name looks like `Category:0x3eb7d90`

here is my view, its just a basic scaffold but i added the `.name`

```
<p>
 <b>Category:</b>
  <%= @treatment.category.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @treatment.name %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE an HTML SELECT BOX and set the values to the id values and the text to the names of the categories.
If you need to save more than 1 id then you can use javascript to append a hidden input with the value of the id to save when the form is posted.

Comment: `<%= f.select(:category, :category_id, Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:prompt => 'Velja flokk'})%>`        this is what i have at the moment but it gives me an error `undefined method merge` for my categories

Comment: Okey so the problem was that i couldnt use the form object `f.` in the select box but the `categorie_id` didnt get saved

Comment: does your select box have a name attribute? can you show the HTML when you view the page source in the browser?

Comment: i posted the html but im not sure what you mean by named attribute ? if you mean the name of the attribute im trying to tie to this select box then its `:category`

Comment: well it won't save the first option too well since the value is null, might want to make the value 0 for that

Comment: what gets posted when you submit the form?

Comment: the first option is just a prompt telling ppl to pick a catagory, if its not changed it leads to an error thou :P i also noticed from the html that i had `id="category_category_id` the first should have been treatment now i can see that the tables are conected but instead of showing the categorie name it shows `#<Category:0x3eb7d90>` ill also post my view too :D

Comment: well i figured out that i was just calling the category.name in a wrong way, it should have been `<%= @treatment.category.name %>` but your replay about checking the html got me on the right track so ill mark this as the answer, thanks mate :)

Comment: glad i could sort of help even though i don't know any ruby :)